# Android Developer Console does not track "Crashes & ANRs"

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

To track crashes on my app I do use Crashlytics/Fabric, but I also would like to have some statistics on Google Play Developer Console, inside the section "Crashes & ANRs". 
It happens all the crashes are being tracked in Crashlytics/Fabri but not on Google Play developer console. This section is completely empty for my project.

How can I setup this? As I understood no setup is needed to track crashes on Google Play Dev Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything to set it up. When your app is distributed through google play and it crashes, it is up to the user to click 'Send report' to send a crash report to google play that you can then look at.

If users don't send reports, you won't get any.

Comment: Doesnt it make this "functionality" (Crashes & ANRs) kind of ..not useful? :/

Comment: If you want to do it through google play, this is how it's gonna be. You depend on users to send reports to you, it's not an automated process

Comment: There are tools like ACRA http://www.acra.ch/ that allow you to collect crashs reports from within the app that can automatically be send to your backend, but this is not related to google play

Comment: I already use Crashlytics/Frabirc that does a great work. I would just expect Google Play to have similar behaviour. I hope in future we can just initialise a component, set a flag... and google play console takes care of it for us. Thank for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

it's the final user responsibility. if he report craches and bugs you will be informed in the section Crashes & ANRs. This is why it's highly recommended to use tracker in your app if you want to have all the stats you want.